# Cannot delete a mnesia table that I know exists

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

I have a mnesia table that I am trying to delete. However, when I try to run `:mnesia.delete(TableName)` I get this error back `{:aborted, {:no_exists, TableName}}`

When I try to create the same table by running `:mnesia.create_table(TableName, [attributes: [:id, :att1, :att2], disc_copies: [Node.self()]])` I get this back `{:aborted, {:already_exists, TableName}}`

I can still see the `.DCD` file for the table after a delete, what causes this and how can I fix it?

Note: The code is in an Elixir codebase.

Edit: When my application starts, I try to delete and recreate that table, even if it exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`:mnesia.delete/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#delete-1) looks for a key to delete in the given table (and takes a tuple `{Table, Key}`).

You probably want [`:mnesia.delete_table/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#delete_table-1) which will delete the table itself.

Docs for more: http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#delete_table-1